# Angular @Output: Can we detect if function is done when emitting?

Tags: angular, output, observable, angular-components, eventemitter

I have an `Angular` `Component` with an `Output`. When I `emit` an `event` to this `output`, an `async` function will be called (this function is outside of the component).

Inside the `component`, I'd like to know when this outside function has finished. Is there any way to do that?

Here's some of the code of my component:

```
@Output() action: EventEmitter<string>;

itemClicked(item) {
    this.action.emit();
    // When the function of the observer is done: this.hideMenu();
}
```

And here's the code outside of the component:

```
<my-component (action)="getData()"></my-component>


getData() : Promise<any> {
    ...
}
```

Is there any way to detect that the "getData" function has finished inside of the component?

In AngularJS I could do it like this:

```
scope: {
    action: '&'
}
...

    scope.itemClicked = function(item) {
        $q.when(item.action()).finally(function() {
            scope.hideMenu();
        });
    };
```

**EDIT**:

I was thinking in another solution inspired by `Ionic`'s refresher. What if the emit() call passes the instance of my component as a parameter? That way the getData function could do something like:

```
getData(menu): Promise<any> { 
    ...
    menu.hideMenu();
}
```

What do you think about this solution? If you think it's wrong then I guess I'll go with the `Input`.

Comment: You can make an Input for that. Something like: `@Input() actionDone: boolean;` and set this in your parent component and pass it along to your `my-component`

Comment: I would simply define an input property for menuHidden: boolean trough a setter

Comment: I edited my post to add a possible solution I just thought of. Can you please tell me what you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS `&` binding was incorrectly translated to Angular. The proper counterpart is `Input`:

```
@Input() actionCallback: () => Promise<any>;

itemClicked(item) {
    this.actionCallback().then(...);
}
```

Which is used like:

```
<my-component [actionCallback]="getData">
```

While `Output` provides one-way interaction that isn't supposed to feed back. `getData` should be aware of its responsibilities and provide the feedback, through a callback or RxJS subject:

```
@Output() action: EventEmitter<Function>;

itemClicked(item) {
    this.action.emit(this.onClick);
}

onClick = () => {
  this.hideMenu();
}
```

Which is used like:

```
<my-component (action)="getData($event)"></my-component>

getData(callback) : Promise<any> {
    ...
    .then(callback);
}
```

Comment: I've used the callback approach, your "second" solution, and it works for me. Maybe the @Input solution is better in terms of architecture, but this one is more simple so I chose it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use an `@Input` to send the completed message when the function is done and in the interested component listen for the input with the `set` and do what you want knowing that the function is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Host property to get the parent like so

```
@Output() action: EventEmitter<string>;

constructor(@Host() private parent: ParentComponent) {
    parent.getData().subscribe(...);
}
```

**EDIT** Type your parent as an abstract class

```
constructor(@Host() private parent: ConcernedParent) {
    parent.getData().subscribe(...);
}

export abstract class ConcernedParent {
  public abstract getData(): Observable<any>;
}
```

Comment: that would tightly couple the child component to its parent though, not truly reusable

Comment: As Jota.Toledo said, I want this component to be used in several places of my app, so this solution isn't suitable for me :)

Comment: Anyways, if you want to re-use it, use this solution, and instead of typing your parent with a component, type with with an Interface/mother class, that has to implement a `getData` function. I mean, sure, you want to re-use it, but you still have to comply to something, and the least you can comply to is a function name

Comment: BTW, this will invoke the getData method on component instantiation, but OP wants to call that method only on event emit. So this doesnt really fulfill that. If getData is an observable that will emit when the data fetching is complete or not, you are basically defining an input property as already explained in the other answer.

Comment: Like a madman of course. I followed OP's signature, but I should have went with my take on it. Edited my answer. And you can declare getData as a Subject if you want to have it on emit. I answered the OP on the basis he asked, and he forgot to mention key factors. So yeah, I'm not making a complete answer here, bear with me same as I bear with him !